# Fixing Modals in Flowbite-Svelte, Basic example not working

Tags: typescript, modal-dialog, svelte, vite, flowbite

I’m trying to get Svelte, Flowbite and TypeScript working together. I was specifically testing the ability to handle modal dialog boxes. I found in my first round of testing that I could bring modals up from a button but not from code. So I tried again.

- I created a new virtual machine running Linux
- I followed the `[Getting Started][1]` (https://flowbite-svelte.com/pages/getting-started) guide
- The site came up

To the index.svelte file I tried to import the modal code by entering:

```
<script>
    import { Modal } from 'flowbite-svelte'
</script>
```

Now when I run the site I get:

> 500
>
> Cannot find module 'svelte-heros' imported from
> '/home/test/Projects/modal/node_modules/flowbite-svelte/accordions/AccordionItem.svelte'
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'svelte-heros' imported from
> '/home/test/Projects/modal/node_modules/flowbite-svelte/accordions/AccordionItem.svelte'
> at viteResolve (file:///home/test/Projects/modal/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-71eb12cb.js:50410:25)
> ...

I've used npm to install 'svelte-heros' but it didn't change anything.

What might I be doing wrong here and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.
Just run: `npm install svelte-heros`
It's listed in features here [one click away](https://flowbite-svelte.com/pages/flowbite-svelte-starter).